# Populating Django Template with Variables and Database Data?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django to create an application with different types of words / terms. On one page, you may have the title "Terms" and then a list of terms. On another page, you have the exact same thing but for phrases (header, list of phrases).

Is it possible to do something like this -->

1. Store header and list for terms
2. Store header and list for phrases
3. Create **one** template that is used to show headers and lists on a
   page
4. Call some Django function (not sure if this exists) that uses
   the template to generate a page for terms
5. Use that same Django
   function that uses the same template to generate the page for
   phrases

The hope is that I can avoid having one large template folder full of pages that are basically doing the same thing. For example, right now, if I wanted to add phrases_in_spanish and phrases_in_french, I'd have to add two new templates that are basically doing the same thing --> showing the header and the list. All I want to do is store the header and list somewhere and have Django do the rest of the work to create the pages. So I could technically have 1,000 pages without having to write 1,000 different template files that are all just showing headers and lists.

**Template example:**

```
{% extends "profile/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <a href="{% url 'profile:new_term' %}">Add a New Term</a>
            <p>Terms:</p>
            <ul>
                {% for term in terms %}
                    <li><p><a href="{% url 'profile:term' term.id %}">{{ term.name }}</a> : {{ term.definition }}</p></li>
                    <a href="{% url 'profile:edit_term' term.id %}">Edit Term</a>
                    <a href="{% url 'profile:delete_term' term.id %}">Delete Term</a>
                {% empty %}
                    <li>No terms have been added yet.</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you mean, "create a new page"? Where are you creating new pages, and why?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried to edit the question for clarity. Please let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create an html template for each page.

You have to create a URL dispatcher on `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^(P<list_name>\w+)/$', views.your_view)
```

So instead of having many templates that have the same structure, you render only one with the info you want.

So your view should look like this:

```
def your_view(request, list_name):
    list = get_object_or_404(List, pk=list_name)
    context = {
        'list_info':list.info
    }
   return render(request, 'your_app/template.html', context)
```

Of course in this example you need to have a table called `List` on your database with primary key `list_name`.

Comment: But in order to tell the view which one I want (e.g. term, phrase, etc.), don't I have to pass that info to the view from the template? For example, if I want the list of terms, I need an html template page that calls the view like {% url 'profile:term_view' term_list %}. So, I'd still have to have a page for each thing telling it what to call. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you need to pass it to the view but why would you need a separate template for each one? You would just generate a list of the options and have a link for each item, surely?

Comment: I think I got it now. I needed to go back and read how Django sets everything up (my first Django project). I also needed to get out of my head that a template != a static web page. Here's what I'm getting from the answer and comments --> I set up the URL. When I go to that URL, the view receives the list item to use from the request/parameters from the URL. The view takes that info, sets the context and renders the page using the generic template.  Let me try the suggestion in the answer, then I'll mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be possible to have a model called something generic like `Concept` (this could be Terms or Phrases or Headers or something similar) with a related model like `ConceptDetail` (which could be a list of terms or list of phrases, etc).

Then you have one URL config but different concepts have different PKs which appear in the URL to differenciate them (you can also use slugs in URL as kwargs to make the URLs more readable). For example:

```
path('concept/', ConceptListView.as_view()),
path('concept/<slug:concept_name>/', ConceptDetailView.as_view()),
```

As for views and templates, you have a `ListView` that shows you all the concepts (here you can add filtering and other search options) and then in the `DetailView` of each concept you could display its related ConceptDetail instances.

Does this sound like something that could help you?